# Backgorund Image with EditText and Button in Android

Tags: android

I am very novice android developer who is struggling to know the things.I have a image which has a `EditText` field and some buttons.So we can say we have EditText and button as user input controls available.Now i want to use this image as the background image as..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:background="@drawable/bg">
</LinearLayout>
```

So my question here is how can i get the input value from the `EditText` field and how can i set the Events for the button..

Please help me..

Comment: You have to separate everything, the background should be plain.

Comment: why you can't  get the input value from the `EditText` field ,what is the issue you are facing >?

Comment: @Sree How can i get the input value from the background image?

Comment: @Nun'eChai Will you please explain ,i am very novice..

Comment: show us what you have tried ,Better you go through some basic tutorials in android which help to solve your issue

Comment: Check the answer below. Hope that helps, dont hesistate to ask if you dont understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/the_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Set" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your Java code:

Declare class level:

```
EditText edit1, edit2; 
Button bt;
```

in your on create:

```
edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
bt = (button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

bt.setOnclickListener(onCLi);
```

Then declare your onClickListener outside of onCreate:

```
private View.OnClickListener onCli = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String editvalue1 = edit1.getText().toString(); 
            String editvalue2 = edit2.getText().toString(); 

            System.out.prinltn("Value1: "+editvalue1 +"and value2: "+editvalue2);

    }
};
```

Complete Java implementation:

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    EditText edit1, edit2; 
    Button bt; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
        edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
        bt = (button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnclickListener(onCLi);  

    }
    private View.OnClickListener onCli = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String editvalue1 = edit1.getText().toString(); 
            String editvalue2 = edit2.getText().toString(); 

            System.out.prinltn("Value1: "+editvalue1 +"and value2: "+editvalue2);

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I got your answer and have few doubts as i am trying to learn android,I will say this is my first class.I want to know how can i style my **EditText** and how can i add an image on button as i have seen it in almost all apps.Please help ..Thanks

Comment: Just add a background image in the button using the following in xml: `android:background ="@drawable/buttonimage"` the same can be done with edit text. I have updated the xml in the answer above, check it for reference.

Comment: I down voted your question because there was room for improvement, please do not take it otherwise.